# Randomise order of specific children elements only

Tags: jquery

I am trying to randomise the order of some children elements with a specific class inside a div that already contains other children elements.

I am using this, but I want to keep the order of the elements without this specific class rather than shuffle them all.

```
$(function () {
    var parent = $(".slider-thumbs .swiper-wrapper");
    var divs = parent.children();
    while (divs.length) {
        parent.append(divs.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * divs.length), 1)[0]);
    }
});
```

Is there a way to shuffle children elements with an specific class without affecting the ones without this class?

Thanks

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor. It si impossible to guess how shuffling some elements will work if you do not shuffle all children

Answer (score 0):

Let's brute force our way. Shuffle, check, repeat. Then push one by one to the original parent by the order of shuffling.

```js
function shuffle(a) {
  var j, x, i;
  for (i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    x = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = x;
  }
  return a;
}

function did_only_free_moved(arr, original) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (original[i] == 0 && arr[i].classList.contains("free")) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

function shuffle_free_children(elem) {
  var arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(elem.children);
  var original = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    original.push(arr[i].classList.contains("free") ? 1 : 0);
  }
  do {
    arr = shuffle(arr)
  } while (!did_only_free_moved(arr, original))
  var i = 0;
  while (i < arr.length) {
    elem.appendChild(arr[i]);
    i++
  }
}

function do_it() {
  shuffle_free_children(document.querySelector("ul"))
}
```

```css
li {
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 2px;
}

.free {
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li class="free">item 2</li>
  <li class="free">item 3</li>
  <li>item 4</li>
  <li class="free">item 5</li>
  <li>item 6</li>
  <li>item 7</li>
  <li class="free">item 8</li>
  <li class="free">item 9</li>
</ul>

<button onclick="do_it()">shuffle</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assumed you want children that without the specific class `shuffle` will remain at the same position.

First give the `shuffle` class to the element that you want to included in the shuffle.

```
<div>remain 1</div>
<div>remain 2</div>
<div class="shuffle">SHUFFLE 1</div>
<div>remain 3</div>
<div class="shuffle">SHUFFLE 2</div>
<div class="shuffle">SHUFFLE 3</div>
```

Get the children which should included in shuffle.

```
const children = $(parent).children(".shuffle");
```

Convert the `children` to array, perform shuffle.

```
const shuffled = shuffleArray(children.toArray());
```

Then loop through the original children, replace each child with rearranged child.

```
children.each((currentIndex, child) => {
    $(child).replaceWith($(shuffled[currentIndex]).get(0).outerHTML);
})
```

**Demo:**

```js
function shuffle() {
  /* shuffle with Fisher-Yates algorith */
  const shuffleArray = array => {
    return array.reduce(
      (newArray, _, i) => {
        var random = i + (Math.floor(Math.random() * (newArray.length - i)));
        [newArray[random], newArray[i]] = [newArray[i], newArray[random]];
        return newArray;
      }, [...array]);
  };

  const shuffleChildren = (parentIndex, parent) => {
    /* first get children with class "shuffle" */
    const childs = $(parent).children(".shuffle");

    /* shuffle the children, return rearranged children */
    const shuffled = shuffleArray(childs.toArray());

    /* loop through each child */
    childs.each((currentIndex, child) => {
      /* replace the original child with new order child */
      $(child).replaceWith($(shuffled[currentIndex]).get(0).outerHTML);
    })
  };

  /* loop though multiple parent to do shuffle */
  $(".parent").each(shuffleChildren);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="shuffle()">Shuffle</button>
<div class="parent">
  <div>remain 1</div>
  <div>remain 2</div>
  <div class="shuffle">SHUFFLE 1</div>
  <div>remain 3</div>
  <div class="shuffle">SHUFFLE 2</div>
  <div class="shuffle">SHUFFLE 3</div>
  <div>remain 4</div>
  <div>remain 5</div>
  <div class="shuffle">SHUFFLE 4</div>
  <div>remain 6</div>
  <div class="shuffle">SHUFFLE 5</div>
  <div class="shuffle">SHUFFLE 6</div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```